# how to convert all inbound requests to UTF-8 in Play! framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, netty

Due to backward compatibilities, all HTTP requests not having defined charset are converted to ISO-8859-1 by default. Our netty served Play! application correctly receives PUT requests with JSON body, if those requests have defined charset. In case it does not, those requests should be converted to UTF-8 somehow, preferably on global application level.

So I have created a Global.scala class which will be in charge of receiving of all inbound 
requests and converting those 'undefined' to UTF-8, which will ensure all requests will be handled properly before getting into their appropriate modules.

```
    import play.*;

    public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {

       return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    }
}
```

in this 'filter' method now there is missing code piece which will query if request is PUT or POST and does not have character encoding defined, and will convert this request's body to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1, otherwise it will convert request's body to UTF-8 from whatever charset it is in.

Apache Tomcat has this resolved thru Filters: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3

I have not found anything in Netty similar to Tomcat's features, only this Global interceptor on Play! level.

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: how to convert what is in request to UTF-8 before passing it over to its intended spot...

Comment: I don't think this is supported directly, you will need to modify Play itself, maybe add a getter to Http.RequestBody for example. But I do not see how you could magically convert 'undefined' to UTF-8, in some way you need to know what your input is, either by trusting the headers or implicitly (you know your legacy code always sends in a specific encoding or some such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Request`object has a `body()` method that returns the body of the request.

That body, of type `RequestBody`, has an `asRaw()` method that returns a [Http.RawBuffer](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/mvc/Http.RawBuffer.html).

From there you can obtain the byte[] of the body and process it as you want. For example, `String` allows you to create a String from a byte[] indicating the Charset (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)), and as you can obtain the `charset` from the headers in the request, you can then create the right String.

**EDIT:**

On answer to the comment, to apply this you probably want to use a [BodyParser](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaBodyParsers) instead of the `Global`  class

Comment: ok, how to return such reparsed data back into request so the endpoint where this reqeust is meant to end will get request with appropriately converted data. Request is immutable and therefore I have a problem doing it on transparent way